# Clear Only Rectangle Drawing(Not Markers)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/wa0hwc2s/) and let me know how I can clear ONLY the Rectangle (Not Markers) after zoom in finshed.

I already tried adding the `map.setMap(null);` into `rectanglecomplete` but it is not working besides I think this might remove all drawing even the markers from the map which I do not want to do

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager,'rectanglecomplete',function(r) {
            map.fitBounds(r.getBounds());
            map.setMap(null);
        });
```

> **Update**

I also tried this:

```
 var drawings = [];
 function deleteRect() {
        for (var i=0; i < drawings.length; i++)
        {
          drawings[i].overlay.setMap(null);
        }
        drawings = [];
      }
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager,'rectanglecomplete',function(r) {
 drawings.push(r);
 map.fitBounds(r.getBounds());
 deleteRect()
});
```

but still no success and I am getting the

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined

in the console!

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var drawingManager
$(document).ready(function () {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.241943, -122.889318);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
                   google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
        }
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager,'rectanglecomplete',function(r) {
        map.fitBounds(r.getBounds());
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

});
```

```css
body {
    padding-top:25px;
}
#map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a transparent rectangle this way

```
 drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
               google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
    },
        rectangleOptions: {
          fillColor: '#cccccc',
          fillOpacity: 0,
          strokeWeight: 5,
        }        
});
```

and for remove the rectangle use

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager,'rectanglecomplete',function(r) {
    map.fitBounds(r.getBounds());
    r.setMap(null);
});
```

like this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/o60L1901/)

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge, but what I need it removing the drawing from the map.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot but why `r` ? how? I got confused!

Comment: Well. `r` is the rectangle object. In the listener you use a callback function(r). This function is executed when event is raised by the related object named `r` and passed to the function